# Change Pivottable SourceData via VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a macro enabled template which includes a lot of pivotTables which need to be manually update (including the sourcedata change) 
A few days ago i was working with this code solution, which was actually working so well

```
Sub Button12_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivots")

'CE OP Pivot Tables
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable2"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable3"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable3").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable4"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable4").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable5"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable5").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable6"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable6").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable7"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable7").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable27"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable27").RefreshTable

'SLED Pivot Tables
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable8"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable8").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable9"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable9").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable10"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable10").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable11"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable11").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable12"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable12").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable13"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable13").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable14"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable14").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable30"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="SLED_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable30").RefreshTable

'CA Pivot tables
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable15"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable15").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable16"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable16").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable17"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable17").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable18"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable18").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable19"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable19").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable20"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable20").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable21"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable21").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable31"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CA_2_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable31").RefreshTable

'CE Future POs
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable22"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable22").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable23"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable23").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable24"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable24").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable25"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable25").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable26"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable26").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable28"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable28").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable29"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable29").RefreshTable

    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable32"). _
    ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_Future_POs_Table")
    sh.PivotTables("PivotTable32").RefreshTable


End Sub
```

But since this morning, every time I click the button that runs this macro, I have been receiving the same message

> runtime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument

So far I have tried to use a table instead of a range (as you can see in the posted code. Also, the range names are exactly the same minus the _Table part) but I still see that annoying message.

I have also validated and none of the PivotTables, nor the Sheet have changed its name so I think that's not one of the issues.

Also,  I have changed the ranges to include and ignore the headers of the table and still nothing.

Also (x3) the same ranges are used on another modules to perform some formatting to the cells

The debugger always stops on the first pivot table

```
sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")
```

Any idea what I'm missing or not doing right or changed without noticing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does it help if you refer to the source data as `SourceData:=Range("CE_2_Table").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True)`?

Comment: @Domenic though would External be True? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: You're creating multiple pivot caches with the same source: have you tried creating only one of each, and pointing your pivot table to it?

Comment: @BigBen That's strange, it did accept it when I tested it.  I tested it using Excel 2016.

Comment: @Domenic I tried as you said on your first comment and I got a  "runtime error -2147024809 (80070057) - Pivot Table field name is not valid"
 if I try with the actual range name instead of the table, I get the same "runtime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried to do this but i got a  
**runtime error 424 object required**  following this example  
`Dim pvtcch As PivotCache`  
`Dim pvtcchs As PivotCaches`  
`Set pvtcch = pvtcchs.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")`  
`sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _`  
`ChangePivotCache pvtcch`

Comment: Try `Dim pvtcch As PivotCache: 
 Set pvtcch = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="CE_2_Table")`

Comment: @TimWilliams now it's the same **runtime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument** again

Comment: Make sure that you don't have one or more empty column headers.  Also, if you have any columns that are hidden, try un-hiding them.

Comment: @Domenic all the ranges have their respective headers and no hidden columns whatsoever. I do have blank values inside the table but that shouldn't be a problem ¿right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't make a difference.  I tested it with Excel 2016 and 2007.  For me, both your original reference and the one I offered worked with Excel 2016 and 2007.

Comment: If you supplied it a string that refers to the source data in an R1C1 reference style will it accept it `(ie. "'Sheet1'!R1C1:R100C5")` ?

Comment: @Domenic nope, still getting the runtime error 5. I tried this way  `Dim kCE As Long
    kCE = ce.Range("B28", ce.Range("B28").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 27`
`ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'CE-Cases-OP'!B28:S" & kCE)` and i also tried by creating a Range variable, but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had some slicers that were the ones that made the code fail.   All i had to do was erase them and then the Sub worked again